# careers.stackoverflow.com seems to be down

Tags: support, jobs

It's not coming up for me in Utah, and [downforeveryoneorjustme](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/careers.stackoverflow.com) seems to see that it's down as well.

Here is the traceroute for me from utah.
[image]

Comment: Looks up for me, even though your link say's it down.

Comment: It is appearing here in South Texas just fine. Searches appear to be working too.

Comment: Working in Central Ohio

Comment: Working in Argentina.

Comment: @jprofitt good call, fixed that :)

Comment: Working in Texas.

Comment: Works in Pennsylvania.

Comment: it is odd that i can reach meta, but not careers

Comment: Working in Finland

Comment: Working in Colorado.

Comment: Working in beautiful Georgia, where *everything* is Peachtree. Your link does still say that it's down, though.

Comment: Working in UK :)

Comment: Works from The Netherlands

Comment: Works in Belgium.

Comment: Thanks for the report, I have a ticket open on our side - Internap is going to poke XO communications to get this resolved.